# How do i get a smooth Javascript/CSS transition between survey answers?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a small survey widget that sits at the bottom right hand corner of the page. It's using Survicate to display a 4 or 5 question survey.

The user clicks an answer in one of the 'surv-radio' divs and the javascript loads another question in the divs.

```
<div class="surv-body">
  <div class="surv-hgroup">
    <div class="surv-description">Good morning. I've noticed you're a regular around here.
    </div>
    <div class="surv-title">Would you be interested in letting me know how you rate our app?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="surv-aligner-box">
    <div class="surv-radio" data-user_tag="" data-value="109747"> 
      <span class="surv-answer">Happy to help!</span> 
    </div>
    <div class="surv-radio" data-user_tag="" data-value="109748"> 
      <span class="surv-answer">Maybe later</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue here is that the div just loads the new content straight away. I'm looking for a smooth maybe fade in/fade out transition over a second or so between each question.

I tried some CSS here but could only get the transition to work when the very first set of questions is loaded.

```
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
```

If possible, I would like a raw Javascript solution without jQuery as well please.

Thanks

Comment: Please, share de CSS you tried...

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: To detail BSMP's request, I would say a good MCV example would include at least the Javascript used to hide one question and show the next; ideally, placing the two in different divs.